# How can I pass a mouse-click method as a parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, action, func

I want to make an extension **method** which fills a stackpanel with buttons.

In order to do this I have to **pass in a mouse-click-handler**.

**What type does the `mouseClickHandler` parameter have to be here?**

I know it's something like these but they all don't work:

- `delegate`
- `Func<object, RoutedEventArgs>`
- `Action<>`

Code:

```
public static void FillMenuWithPages(this StackPanel spMenu, string menuIdCode, 
            PagingManager pagingManager, ??????? mouseClickHandler)
{
    var menuPageItems = PageItems.GetPageItemsWithMenu(menuIdCode);
    spMenu.Children.Clear();
    foreach (var pageItem in menuPageItems)
    {
        var button = new Button();
        button.Content = pageItem.Title;
        button.Margin = new Thickness { Right = 3 };
        button.Tag = pageItem.IdCode;
        button.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(mouseClickHandler);
        if (pageItem.IdCode == pagingManager.CurrentPageItemIdCode)
            button.IsEnabled = false;
        spMenu.Children.Add(button);
    }
}
```

I would call it like this:

```
QuickMenu.FillMenuWithPages("quick", PagingManager, Menu_Button_Click);
```

and this is the mouse click hander:

```
void Menu_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string pageItemIdCode = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag.ToString();
    PagingManager.SwitchPage(pageItemIdCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as a `RoutedEventHandler` like so:

```
public static void FillMenuWithPages(this StackPanel spMenu, string menuIdCode,
            PagingManager pagingManager, RoutedEventHandler mouseClickHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether it's a WPF or Winforms application. For WPF it would be `RoutedEventHandler` (as mentioned in the [`ButtonBase.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) documentation). For winforms, it's `EventHandler` (as seen in the [`Control.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) documentation).